# How can I implement Dynamic React Table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

I want to implement dynamic table  in react js.

Mean the user enter n cross n (row,column) and table of n cross n is formed, after the formation user can enter data in cells of table and can save it in backend

I have searched a lot, but quite confused,whats the better way to implement.What would be preferable data grid, react-table or any other that can be easy to implement?

So I need Suggestion or any source from where I can Implement it or learn it

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to use `ag-grid` for react as its simple and feature rich API,`ag-grid` can be use with React, Angular, Vue and many other. For
 `React` check this  [React Data Grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-getting-started/)